# Eclipse sort folders alphabetically in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, ide

Is there a possibility to sort the folders in the Package Explorer alphabetically?

[image: Package explorer]

Comment: `Project Explorer` will by default sorts alphabetically.

Comment: Your Maven project looks really strange violating best practice with folder structure etc.

Comment: I know, if I tidy it up "mvn clean install eclipse:eclipse" will make this up again. Is this the real cause of this situation?

Comment: Have you tried sorting the source folders in the eclipse build path dialog of the project?

Comment: Yes, I did. But "mvn clean install eclipse:eclipse" will revert this.

Answer (score 1):

The entries in the Referenced libraries node in the package explorer are displayed in the order they are defined in the .classpath file. (thanks to @khmarbaise and Thierry Monney)